# writing a python script that calls different directories

Tags: python, bash

It's kind of hard to explain but I'm using a directory that has a number of different files but essentially I want to loop over files with irregular intervals

so in pseudocode I guess it would be written like:

```
A = 1E4, 1E5, 5E5, 7E5, 1E6, 1.05E6, 1.1E6, 1.2E6, 1.5E6, 2E6

For A in range(start(A),end(A)):
   inputdir ="../../../COMBI_Output/Noise Studies/[A] Macro Particles/10KT_[A]MP_IP1hoN0.0025/"
```

Run rest of code

Because at the moment I'm doing it manually by changing the value in `[A]` and its a nightmare and time consuming. I'm using `Python` on a macbook so I wonder if writing a `bash` script that is called within `Python` would be the right idea?

Or replacing `A` with a text file, such that its:

```
import numpy as np

mpnum=np.loadtxt("mp.txt")
for A in range(0,len(A)):
   for B in range(0,len(A)):
       inputdir ="../../../COMBI_Output/Noise Studies/",[A] "Macro Particles/10KT_",[A]"MP_IP1hoN0.0025/"
```

But I tried this first and still had no luck.

Comment: a couple of remarks about your try: 1st) for A in range(0, len(A)) doesn't mean a lot (loop variable and measuring the length of an integer) 2nd) if you want to build a string with an integer value in it I would suggest something like myString = 'this is a value %i' % intVariable

Comment: Programming by syntax-guessing? Try `for a in ["1E4", "1E5", "5E5", ...]: inputdir = "../..." + a + "..."`

Comment: tobias.. (y) that worked thanks.. im new to python so still trying to get used to it but thanks for the advice grimmy

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are almost there. You don't need a range, just iterate over the list. Then do a replacement in the string using format.

```
A = ['1E4', '1E5', '5E5', '7E5', '1E6', '1.05E6', '1.1E6', '1.2E6', '1.5E6', '2E6']
for a in A:
   inputdir = "../../../COMBI_Output/Noise Studies/{} Macro Particles/10KT_{}MP_IP1hoN0.0025/".format(a)
```

Answer (score 0):

The idea of putting the file names in a list and simply iterating over them using
    for a in A:
seems to be the best idea. However, one small suggestion, if I may, instead of having a list, if you're going to have a large number of files inside this list, why not make it a dictionary? In this way, you can iterate through your files easily as well as keep a count on them.